# Customize Request class from Volley framework

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to use a custom version of Request class from android Volley framework. I managed to work GET custom request but it fails with POST. I'm ovverriding getBody() method and returning byte[]. But Volley complains that connections are already open.

Code:

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("date_in_millis", this.newsDateInMillis);
        json.put("title", URLEncoder.encode(this.newsTitle.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""), "UTF-8"));
        return new StringEntity("data=" + json.toString(), "UTF-8").toString().getBytes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535): [177] NetworkDispatcher.run: Unhandled exception     
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535):     at java.net.URLConnection.checkNotConnected(URLConnection.java:464)
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535):     at java.net.URLConnection.setDoOutput(URLConnection.java:878)
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:225)
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:210)
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:106)
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535):     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:93)
05-24 21:51:08.076: E/Volley(5535):     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:105)
```

Any one used Volley Request this way?

Thanks

Comment: I just tried this. No exceptions here. Might help if you post more of this class.
Do you make any requests before this one?

Comment: I also have override the getHeader() as well but I don't think that can cause trouble. If any one give me a sample code to post a File  along with some text meta data using Volley that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to inherit JsonRequest (or JsonObjectRequest) from Volley\toolbox because then all you need to do is to pass requestBody string to superclass contructor

```
public JsonRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody, Listener<T> listener,
        ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, errorListener);
    mListener = listener;
    mRequestBody = requestBody;
}
```

You can still override e.g parseNetworkResponse and parseNetworkError as need be. If you really need to inherit Request, you should check how JsonRequest implements getBody() and getBodyContentType().